# Custom KeyboardEvent does not bubble

Tags: javascript, dom-events, event-bubbling

For some reason, my custom `KeyboardEvent` does not bubble.
I attend to handle holding key:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
  var isPressed = false;
  var startTimeStamp;

  document.addEventListener('keydown', function (e) {    
    if (!isPressed) {
      startTimeStamp = e.timeStamp;
      isPressed = true;
    }
  });

  document.addEventListener('keyup', function (e) {
    isPressed = false;

    var eventDuration = e.timeStamp - startTimeStamp;

    var _e = new KeyboardEvent('keyheld', {
      bubbles: true,
      cancelBubble: false,
      cancelable: true,
      char: e.char,
      charCode: e.charCode,
      key: e.key,
      keyCode: e.keyCode,
      which: e.which,
      shiftKey: e.shiftKey,
      ctrlKey: e.ctrlKey,
      altKey: e.altKey,
      metaKey: e.metaKey
    });

    Object.defineProperty(_e, 'detail', {
        value: {
            duration: eventDuration
        },
        enumerable: true
    });

    document.dispatchEvent(_e);
  });
});
```

And then I can handle `keyheld` event with a listener attached to `document`. Nonetheless, a listener attached to anything (below it is *body*) else does not fire at all:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    document.body.addEventListener('keyheld', function (e) {
      console.log('KEY HELD: ', e.detail.duration, e);
    });
});
```

The code above does not work, what even stranger, even with `true` supplied as the third argument of `addEventListener()` which should fire a listener when capturing rather than bubbling.

What may be wrong here?

Comment: try adding it to the window itself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `document.dispatchEvent(event)`, the event [is dispatched with its target set to](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/dispatchEvent) `document`, which is the top-level node in the DOM hierarchy, as can be seen [in an illustration here](https://alistapart.com/article/domtricks2/#section2).

The event would normally [bubble](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4616694/1026) to the parents of the target element, but when the target is `document`, there are no parents (`document.parentNode === null`). Trying to register a capturing listener on the body doesn't work for the same reason.

You probably wanted to dispatch to the target of the original event: `e.target.dispatchEvent(_e)`.